# What is the best practice for wrtting custom module in pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, coding-style, pytorch

```py
class TfidfEmbeds(BaseEmbeds):
    # Input just placeholder
    def __init__(self, _=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit([" ".join(i) for i in train_data])
        # Need these to map features
        self.tfidf_word_list = self.tfidf.get_feature_names()
        self.word_to_ix = {word: i for i, word in enumerate(self.tfidf_word_list)}
        self.cache = {}

    def forward(self, X):
        # Cache
        key = tuple(X)
        if key in self.cache:
            return cache[key]
        # Get text
        words = [word_list[i] for i in X.cpu().numpy()]
        idx = [self.word_to_ix[word] if word in self.word_to_ix else 0 for word in words]
        mask = [False if word in self.word_to_ix else True for word in words]
        outputs = self.tfidf.transform([" ".join(words)])[:, idx].toarray().reshape(-1, 1)
        outputs[mask] = 0
        self.cache[key] = outputs
        return torch.from_numpy(outputs).to(device).float()

    def get_output_dim(self):
        return 1
```

I have the above python code for encoding tfidf feature for a list of documents. I wrapped the code inside `Module` but apparently torch is not really appropriate as I am not using `nn` components. And one cannot save `state_dict` of such class. I want to know what is the proper way of creating such `Module`s in pytorch to allow better integration saving with `.state_dict()`?

Thanks

Comment: Basically, state_dict only cares about parameters and buffers... I'd say that, in your case, it might be easier to just implement a custom state_dict logic (including save and load). You can check [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/f58cc4b444c99f6c9260fa1e10bdad6befec0237/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L692-L880) how it is implemented in the base Module class. It is quite straightforward.

Comment: I didn't know this is an option, Thanks. Though I was thinking if there are `nn` classes that allow easy wrapping of basic python types. So I think `register_buffer` is the only way without modifying the original `state_dict` logic? Though that adds quite a bit complexity handling the tensors.

Comment: and it would also change the semantics, which is usually not desirable in the long term